# How to send data to nested collection in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase has changed and I can't seem to create chat messages like it was done in the previous app.  I searched online but it's still showing the old way.

```js
  createMessages(docId: string, content: string, receivingUserId: string, sendingUserId: string, displayName: string) {
    console.log('createmsg', docId, content, receivingUserId, sendingUserId);
    const chatRef = doc(getFirestore(getApp()), `matches`, `${docId}`, `messages`);

    return addDoc(chatRef, {content});
  }
```

It's a nested collection.  The first collection is 'Matches', docId.  I'd like to create a collection within the "docId" to contain the actual chat message.

I'm getting this error
[image]

What exactly is the proper syntax to add a doc in a collection of another doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
const chatRef = doc(getFirestore(getApp()), `matches`, `${docId}`, `messages`);
```

Since you [call `doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#doc), the type of `chatRef` is a `DocumentReference`. And you can't (in the next line) call `addDoc` on a `DocumentReference`.

Likely what you want is:

```
const chatRef = collection(getFirestore(getApp()), `matches`, `${docId}`, `messages`);
```